# Error on starting the application Puppet in the Generic enablers Cosmos

Tags: bigdata, puppet, yum, fiware

Good afternoon,

I have installed the Generic enablers Cosmos, following the manual [BigData Analysis - Installation and Administration Guide](http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/BigData_Analysis_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide). When I have come to '*Step 7: applying Puppet*' and executed the commands, in the file puppet.err has appeared the following errors:

- Error: Could not prefetch yumrepo provider ' inifilé: Section 'openvz-utils' is already defined, cannot re-defines in/etc/yum.repos.d/openvz.repo

  Description: There is a conflict with the titles (indicated in bold type) of the file /etc/yum.repos.d/cosmos-openvz.repo and /etc/yum.repos.d/openvz.repo .

  cat /etc/yum.repos.d/cosmos-openvz.repo

  > **[openvz-utils]**
  >   ...
  >
  > **[openvz-kernel-rhel6]**
  >   ...

  cat /etc/yum.repos.d/openvz.repo

  > **[openvz-utils]**
  >   ...
  >
  > **[openvz-kernel-rhel6]**
  >   ...
  >
  > [openvz-kernel-rhel6-testing]
  >   ...

  Solution: I have realized a change in the titles of the file /etc/yum.repos.d/openvz.repo, example: [openvz-utils_1]
- Error: Could not prefetch database_grant provider 'mysql': Execution of '/usr/bin/mysql mysql -Be describe user' returned 1: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

  Description: in the folder /var/lib/mysql/ was not found the file mysql.sock.

  Solution: I have installed mysql-server.x86_64:

  > yum install mysql-server.x86_64

  At the end of the installations, I restarted the service:

  > /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
  >   /etc/init.d/mysqld start
- Error: Could not update: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list vzstats' returned 1: Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: **ambari**. Please verify its path and try again

  Description: This error appears in the machine of the Master node, this one is provoked by the configuration of the file *[COSMOS_TMP_PATH]*/puppet/modules/cosmos/manifests/hieradata/*my_environment*/**common.yaml**, indicated in '*Step 6: Puppet configuration*'. Concretely, the URL that use the IP: 130.206.81.65

  Solution: in the file *[COSMOS_TMP_PATH]*/puppet/modules/cosmos/manifests/hieradata /*my_environment*/**common.yaml** to change the line:

  > ambari::params::repo_url: 'http:// 130.206.81.65/cosmos/ambari/'

  (without blank space)

  for

  > ambari::params::repo_url: 'http:// public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/1.x/GA'

  (without blank space)
- Error: Could not update: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list vzstats' returned 1: Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: **cosmos-libvirt**. Please verify its path and try again

  Description: it is the same problem as the previous error. The difficulty in this one is that I cannot modify the file *[COSMOS_TMP_PATH]*/puppet/modules/cosmos/manifests/hieradata /*my_environment*/**common.yaml** in the line:

  > cosmos::params::cosmos_repo_deps_url: '**http:// 130.206.81.65/cosmos/rpms/cosmos-deps**'

  (without blank space)

  Because it is line is used in several files:

  cat /etc/yum.repos.d/cosmos-libvirt.repo

  > [cosmos-libvirt]
  >   name=Cosmos LibVirt with OpenVZ - v1.0.5 - NO PolKIT
  >   baseurl=**http:// 130.206.81.65/cosmos/rpms/cosmos-deps/**/libvirt
  >   gpgcheck=0
  >   priority=10
  >   enabled=1

  cat /etc/yum.repos.d/cosmos-openvz.repo

  > [openvz-utils]
  >   name=OpenVZ utilities
  >   baseurl=**http:// 130.206.81.65/cosmos/rpms/cosmos-deps/**/OpenVZ/openvz-utils
  >   enabled=1
  >   gpgcheck=0
  >   priority=1
  >
  > [openvz-kernel-rhel6]
  >   name=OpenVZ RHEL6-based kernel
  >   baseurl=**http:// 130.206.81.65/cosmos/rpms/cosmos-deps/**/OpenVZ/openvz-kernel- > rhel6
  >   enabled=1
  >   gpgcheck=0
  >   priority=1

  It does not also allow to modify the file previous, in the moment to execute the command (indicated in '*Step 7: applying Puppet*'):

  > puppet apply --debug --verbose \
  >    --modulepath *[COSMOS_TMP_PATH]*/puppet/modules/:*[COSMOS_TMP_PATH]*/puppet/modules_third_party/ \
  >    --environment *my_environment* --hiera_config *[COSMOS_TMP_PATH]*/puppet/modules/cosmos/manifests/hiera.yaml \
  >    --manifestdir *[COSMOS_TMP_PATH]*/puppet/modules/cosmos/manifests/ *[COSMOS_TMP_PATH]*/puppet/modules/cosmos/manifests/site.pp \
  >    > puppet.out 2> puppet.err

  It will erase the modified.

  **Solution: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cosmos-platform/issues/4**

I need help with the error:

- Error: /Stage[main]/Ambari::Server::Config/Augeas[ambari-config-repoinfo]: Could not evaluate: Saving failed, see debug

Might they to throw me a hand with these last error?

Thank you in advance.

PD: Forgive for if it is written badly